# Maven plugin dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I haven't been able to find an answer specifically regarding this problem.

I've successfully installed a patched maven plugin jar file manually (osxappbundle) using the following:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=osxappbundle-maven-plugin-1.0-alpha-4-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DartifactId=osxappbundle-maven-plugin -Dversion=1.0-alpha-4-SNAPSHOT -DgeneratePom=true
```

When the plugin is referred to in the pom, specifically 'bundle', I receive the error:

> Unable to load the mojo 'bundle' in the plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:osxappbundle-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-4-SNAPSHOT'. A required call is missing: org/apache/velocity/exception/MethodInvocationException.

org.apache.velocity is definitely installed and is in my local respository (.m2) but isn't found.  If I manually add the class files into the jar they are found, so this suggests it's not resolving dependencies using the local repository.

I assume this is happening because I manually installed the jar file.

If a jar is manually installed, will it only resolve the dependencies if they are in the jar and not look outside?

The plugin is referenced in the pom like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>osxappbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Show us how You refer to this plugin in pom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugins are handled the same way as project dependencies. Whatever dependencies the original plugin refer to in its `pom.xml` are put on the classpath at runtime.

It is usually sufficient to change the `<version>` tag in the `pom.xml` of the plugin and run `mvn install`. This will install the jar and pom file to your local repository. Use a version which makes clear that it is not an official one, e.g. `1.2.3-CUSTOM-SNAPSHOT`. Then change the dependency to this version in your application's pom file and it should work as expected.

If you must use invoke install plugin directly for any reasons, you should always install a proper `pom.xml` with your jar file. Use `-DpomFile=/path/to/pom.xml` to specify the path to the correct pom of your plugin.
`-DgeneratePom=true` will generate only a minimalistic pom if there isn't already a `pom.xml` for this artifact and version in the repository. This pom file won't specify any dependencies. So never use this option if your jar/plugin has any dependencies.

**References:**

- [Maven Install plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#generatePom)

Comment: I'm confused - what do you think the OP has done wrong? The OP has include `-DgeneratePom=true` in the command line.

Comment: As far a I understood the problem, the OP is trying to replace a plugin, which already worked, with an own implementation. The original plugin seems to have dependencies on other jars which are not loaded because the modified plugin uses a generated `pom.xml` instead of a pom with a correct `dependencies` section.

Comment: That is an excellent response - try and weave some of that wording into the body of your answer, since it wasn't apparent that was your meaning.

Comment: @DuncanJones: Thanks for your feedback, I changed the wording.

Comment: THANK YOU nif! You were spot on! That must have been the only thing I hadn't tried.  I added the dependencies to the generated pom and all the errors cleared.  Many thanks!